# Apache spark-shell error import jars

Tags: jar, apache-spark, apache-spark-1.5.2

I have a local spark 1.5.2 (hadoop 2.4) installation on Windows as explained [here](http://nishutayaltech.blogspot.it/2015/04/how-to-run-apache-spark-on-windows7-in.html).

I'm trying to import a jar file that I created in Java using maven (the jar is *jmatrw* that I uploaded on [here](https://github.com/donpir/JMATRW/releases/tag/v0.1-beta) on github). Note the jar does not include a spark program and it has no dependencies to spark. I tried the following steps, but no one seems to work in my installation:

- I copied the library in *"E:/installprogram/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/jmatrw-v0.1-beta.jar"*
- Edit spark-env.sh and add *SPARK_CLASSPATH="E:/installprogram/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/jmatrw-v0.1-beta.jar"*
- In a command window I run `> spark-shell --jars "E:/installprogram/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/jmatrw-v0.1-beta.jar"`, but it says *"Warning: skip remote jar"*
- In the spark shell I tried to do `scala> sc.addJar("E:/installprogram/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/jmatrw-v0.1-beta.jar")`, it says "INFO: added jar ... with timestamp"

When I type `scala> import it.prz.jmatrw.JMATData`, spark-shell replies with `error: not found: value it`.

I spent lot of time searching on Stackoverflow and on Google, indeed a similar Stakoverflow question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32458368/apache-spark-importing-jars), but I'm still not able to import my custom jar.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two settings in 1.5.2 to reference an external jar. You can add it for the driver or for the executor(s).

I'm doing this by adding settings to the `spark-defaults.conf`, but you can set these at spark-shell or in `SparkConf`.

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /path/to/jar/*
spark.executor.extraClassPath /path/to/jar/*
```

I don't see anything really wrong with the way you are doing it, but you could try the conf approach above, or setting these using `SparkConf`

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/path/to/jar/*")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

In general, I haven't enjoyed working with Spark on Windows. Try to get onto Unix/Linux.

Comment: I added the setting `spark.driver.extraClassPath` to the `spark-defaults.conf` file, and it works! Actually, the SPARK_CLASSPATH was deprecated in Spark 1.0+, as also suggested in the spark logging warnings. Thanks for your time spent reading and answering my question.